# How can I add triangles to an in-memory QgsMeshLayer?

Tags: pyqgis, mesh

I have a large number of Delaunay triangles as `PolygonZ`. I want to construct a mesh from these triangles to be able to visualize and rasterize this as elevation / DEM. I create a mesh in memory and try to add the triangles. But when I call `.meshEditor` on the `QgsMeshLayer`, it returns `None` instead of `QgsMeshEditor`. What am I doing wrong?

Code example:

```
uri = "1.0, 2.0 \n" \
"2.0, 2.0 \n" \
"3.0, 2.0 \n" \
"2.0, 3.0 \n" \
"1.0, 3.0 \n" \
"---" \
"0, 1, 3, 4 \n" \
"1, 2, 3 \n"
    
mesh_layer = QgsMeshLayer(uri, "Memory Mesh", "mesh_memory")
transform=QgsCoordinateTransform()
mesh_layer.startFrameEditing(transform)
editor = mesh_layer.meshEditor()
editor.addPointsAsVertices([QgsPoint(0, 0, 0), QgsPoint(50, 100, 10), QgsPoint(100, 0, 20)], 10)
mesh_layer.stopFrameEditing(transform)
```

Because `editor` is `None`, I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addPointsAsVertices'`

QGIS version: 3.22.3

Comment: QGIS doesn't seem to support mesh editing for every data provider yet. You can check with `mesh_layer.supportsEditing()` if a mesh layer supports editing. It returns `false` using `mesh_memory`, which in turn is causing `editor`  to be `None`, because `startFrameEditing` returns before creating the mesh editor. [src](https://qgis.org/api/qgsmeshlayer_8cpp_source.html#l00957)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As CodeBard commented, if you use e.g. Ugrid as provider type it works just fine. I ended up using this (thanks to Vincent Cloarec & Lukasz Debek of Lutra Consulting):

```
from uuid import uuid4

from qgis.core import (
    QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem,
    QgsCoordinateTransform,
    QgsMesh,
    QgsMeshLayer,
    QgsPoint,
    QgsProcessingUtils,
    QgsProviderRegistry
)

provider_meta = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('mdal')

# create a mesh on disk
mesh = QgsMesh()
temp_mesh_filename = f"{uuid4()}.nc"
temp_mesh_fullpath = QgsProcessingUtils.generateTempFilename(temp_mesh_filename)
mesh_format = 'Ugrid'
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
provider_meta.createMeshData(mesh, temp_mesh_fullpath, mesh_format, crs)

# open the mesh & edit
mesh_layer = QgsMeshLayer(temp_mesh_fullpath, 'editable mesh', 'mdal')
transform = QgsCoordinateTransform()
mesh_layer.startFrameEditing(transform)
vertices = [QgsPoint(0, 0, 0), QgsPoint(50, 100, 10), QgsPoint(100, 0, 20)]
mesh_layer.meshEditor().addPointsAsVertices(vertices, 1)
mesh_layer.meshEditor().addFace([0, 1, 2])
mesh_layer.commitFrameEditing(transform, continueEditing=False)
```